# Web-push-php throwing Class not found exception

Tags: php, push-notification, composer-php, autoload, web-push

So I'm trying to set-up the push-notification service in PHP, and I'm using the web-push-php library from MinishLink. But for some unknown reason (to me) its throwing me  `Class 'Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush' not found`.

I'm not doing anything different(or fancy right now) and just followed all the steps mentioned in this [repo's README.md](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php) .

In the bottom it has FAQs and this issue is also stated (I found it after a couple of hours :( ) and it suggests to add `require __DIR__ . '/path-to-my-vendor/autoload.php';`. But its not working.

Example code from the repo (also, this is what I'm trying my luck with, to just set the web-push up!)

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;
use Minishlink\WebPush\Subscription;

// here I'll get the subscription endpoint in the POST parameters
// but in reality, you'll get this information in your database
// because you already stored it (cf. push_subscription.php)

$auth = array(
    'VAPID' => array(
        'subject' => 'https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example/',
        'publicKey' => file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../keys/public_key.txt'), // don't forget that your public key also lives in app.js
        'privateKey' => file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../keys/private_key.txt'), // in the real world, this would be in a secret file
    ),
);

$webPush = new WebPush($auth);
$subscription = Subscription::create(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true));

$report = $webPush->sendOneNotification(
    $subscription,
    "Hello! "
);

// handle eventual errors here, and remove the subscription from your server if it is expired
$endpoint = $report->getRequest()->getUri()->__toString();

if ($report->isSuccess()) {
    echo "[v] Message sent successfully for subscription {$endpoint}.";
} else {
    echo "[x] Message failed to sent for subscription {$endpoint}: {$report->getReason()}";
}
```

Comment: Did you installed it with composer?

Comment: Hii @Wimanicesir Yes I installed it with the `composer require minishlink/web-push`

Comment: Hii @IncredibleHat Yes I think path for the autoload is correct because if I provide the wrong path it will throw an exception that no file/directory found (since its in require)

Comment: Right, I realized that after asking lol. Have you tried not using `use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;` at the top (comment that line out) and instead try `$webPush = new Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush($auth);` directly?

Comment: @IncredibleHat removing use MinishLink/WebPush/WebPush and then using the inline method was no different... and I got the exact same error

Comment: And Yeah I forgot to update the order of Subscription and webpush instantiation

Comment: and if I use the earlier codesnippet it was breaking up on the subscription and throwing exact same error `class not found` for that particular class... yeah  composer stands nowhere in front of npm ig :(

Comment: Well, this is being a ripe pain then huh. As you say, `require` would cause a fatal error if the path was wrong, so its pulling in SOME sort of file. However the class isn't defined, as it fails trying to use a class. So, this leaves me with one last question.... what exactly is inside the `autoload.php` that is in the `require`? (you could add a screenshot of that to the Q content if you wish not to paste a mile of code)

Comment: Its using composer's autoloader to build this up but I'm  not 100% sure how its working... ```<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInitfd3430704328b-==::getLoader();``` 

Is it usefull somehow?

Comment: It looks legit... however it may be something gone sideways during the whole composer setup and layout. But this is where I have to bow out, as a composer expert could know better (I'm no expert because I avoid composer like the plague LOL). Sorry :(

Comment: No Problems @IncredibleHat .I truly appreciate your help . Let's see If we have some composer expert in the house, thanks!